# How to pass input value from child to parent component react

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm building a table component with inputs to filter the data. My structure is:

- FilterBar
- - FilterInput

I want my FilterBar able to store the FilterInput values in the class state in this way ==> `this.state = {inputsVal: ["input1value", "input2value", "", ...]}`.
I dynamic build an input component for each header (attribute in my database). So when I write in one of those components i want to capture the new value and the position of this component in order to refresh the FilterBar state array. I success on getting the position(index) of the component but not the value. I dont know how to achieve this. Here are my components:

```
class FilterBar extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        inputs: Array(props.headers.length).fill("")
    };
    this.updateFilters = this.updateFilters.bind(this);
}

updateFilters(i) {
    console.log(i);   //==>I can see the index of the input when it changesbut i want also to see the new value
}

renderFilterInputs() {
    var filters = []
    for (let i=0; i < this.state.inputs.length; i++) {
        filters.push(<FilterInput key={i} filterApplied={this.state.inputs[i]} onChange={() => this.updateFilters(i)} />);
    }
    return filters;
}

render() {
    return (
      <tr className="filters-bar">
        {this.renderFilterInputs()}
      </tr>
    );
}
```

}
and here is  FilterInput component

```
class FilterInput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <td>
                <input type='text' className="form-control" defaultValue={this.props.filterApplied} onChange={() => this.props.onChange()} />
            </td>
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change the `FilterInput` `onChange=` handler on the input:

```
<input onChange={event => this.props.onChange(event.target.value)} {...otherProps} />
```

obviously, design an APi contract between the two where you either pass the value or the event raw to the `onChange` handler and in the parent make sure you have:

```
<FilterInput onChange={this.updatefilters.bind(i)} />
```

make sure the `updatefilters` is bound to `this` first in your constructor.

Comment: Thank you, by this way I'm getting the value but I lost the index of the input <:( and it's important for me to track the value of the index!!

Comment: I answer myself, I just added a new parameter in updateFilters function and pass it inside FilterInput onChange handler.
`<input type='text' className="form-control" defaultValue={this.props.filterApplied} onChange={event => this.props.onChange(event.target.value, this.props.keyField)} />`  and the function: `updateFilters(val, i) { ..... }`

Answer (score 1):

Change the onChange as so:

```
filters.push(<FilterInput key={i} filterApplied={this.state.inputs[i]} onChange={(evt) => this.updateFilters(i, evt)} />);
```

Then change your updateFilters to get the value from the event now passed in:

```
updateFilters(i, evt) {
    const value = evt.target.value;
    ....
}
```

Comment: By this way I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined` in the function updateFilters. It seems not be working for me. Thank you anyways!